# Nested form isn't saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I am using the gem Cocoon for nested form and this form don't get submitted...
What am I doing wrong please? Thank u

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h3>Your event to share</h3>
      <%= f.input :name, label: "Event's name" %>
      <%= f.input :total_price, label: "What is the total price" %>
      <h3> Add your friends to share the bill</h3>
      <div id="participants">
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :participants do |participant| %>
          <%= render "participants_fields", f: participant %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="links">
          <%= link_to_add_association "add a friend", f, :participants, partial: "participants_fields", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      </div>
        <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_participants_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.input :first_name, label: "Enter your friend's first name" %>
  <%= f.input :salary, label: "Enter his/her monthly pay" %>
  <div class="links">
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove this friend", f , class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing this relation
   `has_many :participants, inverse_of: :event`

I add has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial to implement nested forms with cocoon gem just few hours ago. You might find it useful.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56xjUOAAZY8

To get a strong understanding of how to create a nested form you should also see this video on how to do it without a gem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pulzZxPkgmE